# Call MDX from T SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, ssas, mdx

I'm using SQL Server 2016.  I am trying to call a MDX statement from a T SQL Stored Procedure.  This is my SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Product].[Material Group].[Material Group].[MEMBER_CAPTION] AS [Material Group],
[MARKET].[Sales Org Ship to Party].[Sales Org Ship to Party].[MEMBER_CAPTION] AS [Sales Org Ship to Party],
[Measures].[_X] AS [VALUE]
FROM OPENQUERY([xxxxxx],-- Linked server

--Starting MDX Query

'WITH MEMBER _X AS   
ROUND(Iif (
Sum (
( [Time].[Period Prog].[-3] : [Time].[Period Prog].[-1] ) ,
[Measures].[Order Quantity - Total m]
) <> 0 ,
Sum (
( [Time].[Period Prog].[-3] : [Time].[Period Prog].[-1] ) ,
[Measures].[Order Quantity - Total m]
) / 
[Measures].[Sum for Material Group m] ,
Null
),4) 
SELECT _X ON 0,  
NON EMPTY ([Product].[Material Group].[Material Group],  
[MARKET].[Sales Org Ship to Party].[Sales Org Ship to Party] 
) ON 1 FROM xxxxxx'
)
```

However, I keep receiving the errors:

> The multi-part identifier "Product.Material Group.Material
>   Group.MEMBER_CAPTION" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier
>   "MARKET.Sales Org Ship to Party.Sales Org Ship to
>   Party.MEMBER_CAPTION" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier
>   "Measures._X" could not be bound.

I have tried wrapping the fields in the original select in single quotes, but then this just pulls the fields names as string through.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `[Product].[Material Group].[Material Group].[MEMBER_CAPTION]` is interpreted as a multi-part name. The column name itself already includes these characters. Try using double quotes to quote the column names (`SELECT "[Product].[Material Group].[Material Group].[MEMBER_CAPTION]"`); this requires `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` to be `ON` (which is the default for most connection libraries). T-SQL's native quoting is also an option, but few people would consider `[[Product]].[Material Group]].[Material Group]].[MEMBER_CAPTION]]]` to be more readable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  Double quotes work - thank you

Comment: @JeroenMostert why not writing an answer?